# How to share the same session between 2 applications

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, redmine

I have 2 applications : the first one is written with ruby (It's redmine) and the second one is a Spring boot app and both are hosted on the same tomcat server.
How can i do that?

Comment: You cannot share the same `HttpSession` object unless you do something awful to the two applications. Do you need to share the *session*, or do you need to share *some data*? Perhaps you are asking the wrong question...

Comment: i want to share the same seession

Answer (score 2):

Sharing sessions is not allowed. By (servlet spec) definition, a session belongs to a single web application.

Reference: [Servlet Spec 4.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-4-pr-spec/servlet-4_0_PR.pdf), section 7.3:

> `HttpSession` objects must be scoped at the application (or servlet context) level. The underlying mechanism, such as the cookie used to establish the session, can be the same for different contexts, but the object referenced, including the attributes in that object, must never be shared between contexts by the container.

There are ways you can probably work-around this limitation by setting-up shared caches, etc. but it will always be brittle and potentially dangerous from a security or resource-usage perspective.

Answer (score 0):

User database or user data file(nosql) with use of a unique-user-auth-token, accessible by two apps (or 3, 4, 5 ...)

Global concept :

1. App request connection :
2. is exist "old auth token" in app storage ?

   - yes -> app send old and request new or same if not expired
   - no -> continue
3. is exist valid auth token on server ?

   - yes (an app is already connected) -> send validated auth token to app
   - no -> set new auth token and send to app, new AT is ready for other app
4. server store what app request connection and is connected
5. apps are now able to exchange datas via the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing Web applications is, at a minimum, Bad Practice (TM): Web Applications are completely separated by design. If both applications easily could reach into each other's session: Imagine what would happen if one would overwrite values that have been set by the other, and both applications expecting different data under the same key name.

If you only need single-sign-on, there's a `SingleSignOnValve` available that will make sure you'll only need to sign in once (provided that you authenticate through the container, e.g. a Tomcat Realm). Check `server.xml` for the commented-out-default-value, or the documentation for more information on authentication and the valve.

You might work around it by implementing the UI in both modules and refer back to a common business logic, but this is a level of architectural change too broad to fit into this answer.